# saving mutiple sensor data to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sensors

I am creating an application to collect multiple (android) mobile sensors data. my application work fine, but when I try to save the data to sqlite tables the application crash and stops working. I created table for each sensor and different insert function each function shall be called in different thread (one thread for each sensor) . how can I store sensors data in the most efficient way

this is my code.

```
public class SenosorsDBAdapter {
private SensorsDBHelper myhelper;
public SenosorsDBAdapter(Context context){ myhelper = new SensorsDBHelper(context); }
public long Accelerometerinsert(int ST,String sensorname, String date,float x,float y,float z) {
    long id=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.CREATION_DATE, date);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.SENSOR_NAME, sensorname);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_0, x);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_1, y);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_2, z);
    if (ST == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        id = db.insert(SensorsDBHelper.TABLE_ACCELEROMETER, null, contentValues);
        Log.i("insertData", "ACCELEROMETER insertData successfully ========================================>");
        db.close();
    }
    return id;
}
public long Gyroscopeinsert(int ST,String sensorname, String date,float x,float y,float z) {
    long id=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.CREATION_DATE, date);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.SENSOR_NAME, sensorname);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_0, x);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_1, y);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_2, z);
    Log.i("Gyroscopeinsert", ST+" ========================================>");
    if (ST == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
        id = db.insert(SensorsDBHelper.TABLE_GYROSCOPE, null, contentValues);
        Log.i("insertData", "Gyroscope insertData successfully ========================================>");
        db.close();
    }
    return id;
}
public long LinearAccelerationinsert(int ST,String sensorname, String date,float x,float y,float z) {
    long id=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.CREATION_DATE, date);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.SENSOR_NAME, sensorname);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_0, x);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_1, y);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_2, z);
    Log.i("LinearAcceinsert", ST+" ========================================>");
    if (ST == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {
        id = db.insert(SensorsDBHelper.TABLE_LinearAcceleration, null, contentValues);
        Log.i("insertData", "LinearAcceleration insertData successfully ========================================>");
        db.close();
    }
    return id;
}
public long RotationVectorinsert(int ST,String sensorname, String date,float x,float y,float z) {
    long id=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.CREATION_DATE, date);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.SENSOR_NAME, sensorname);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_0, x);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_1, y);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_2, z);
    if (ST == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
        id = db.insert(SensorsDBHelper.TABLE_RotationVector, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }
    return id;
}
public long Magnetometerinsert(int ST,String sensorname, String date,float x,float y,float z) {
    long id=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.CREATION_DATE, date);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.SENSOR_NAME, sensorname);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_0, x);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_1, y);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_2, z);
    if (ST == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        id = db.insert(SensorsDBHelper.TABLE_Magnetometer, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }
    return id;
}
public long Orientationinsert(int ST,String sensorname, String date,float x,float y,float z) {
    long id=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = myhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.CREATION_DATE, date);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.SENSOR_NAME, sensorname);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_0, x);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_1, y);
    contentValues.put(SensorsDBHelper.V_2, z);
    if (ST == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
        id = db.insert(SensorsDBHelper.TABLE_Orientation, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }
    return id;
}
static  class SensorsDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sensorsDatabase.db";
    private static final String TABLE_ACCELEROMETER = "ACCELEROMETER_Table";
    private static final String TABLE_GYROSCOPE = "GYROSCOPE_sensorsTable";
    private static final String TABLE_LinearAcceleration = "LinearAcceleration_sensorsTable";
    private static final String TABLE_RotationVector = "RotationVector_sensorsTable";
    private static final String TABLE_Magnetometer = "Magnetometer_sensorsTable";
    private static final String TABLE_Orientation = "RotationOrientation_sensorsTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_Version = 1;  // Database Version
    private static final String UID = "id";     // Column I (Primary Key)
    private static final String CREATION_DATE = "creationdate";// Column II
    private static final String SENSOR_NAME = "sensorname";// Column III
    private static final String V_0 = "firstvalue"; // Column IV
    private static final String V_1 = "secondvalue"; // Column V
    private static final String V_2 = "thirdvalue"; // Column VI
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ACCELEROMETER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ACCELEROMETER + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  + CREATION_DATE + " TEXT," + SENSOR_NAME + " TEXT," + V_0 + " REAL," + V_1 + " REAL," + V_2 + " REAL " + ")";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_GYROSCOPE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_GYROSCOPE + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  + CREATION_DATE + " TEXT," + SENSOR_NAME + " TEXT," + V_0 + " REAL," + V_1 + " REAL," + V_2 + " REAL " + ")";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_LinearAcceleration = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_LinearAcceleration + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  + CREATION_DATE + " TEXT," + SENSOR_NAME + " TEXT," + V_0 + " REAL," + V_1 + " REAL," + V_2 + " REAL " + ")";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_RotationVector = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_RotationVector + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  + CREATION_DATE + " TEXT," + SENSOR_NAME + " TEXT," + V_0 + " REAL," + V_1 + " REAL," + V_2 + " REAL " + ")";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_Magnetometer = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_Magnetometer + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  + CREATION_DATE + " TEXT," + SENSOR_NAME + " TEXT," + V_0 + " REAL," + V_1 + " REAL," + V_2 + " REAL " + ")";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_Orientation = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_Orientation + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  + CREATION_DATE + " TEXT," + SENSOR_NAME + " TEXT," + V_0 + " REAL," + V_1 + " REAL," + V_2 + " REAL " + ")";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE_ACCELEROMETER = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ACCELEROMETER;
    private static final String DROP_TABLE_GYROSCOPE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_GYROSCOPE;
    private static final String DROP_TABLE_LinearAcceleration = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LinearAcceleration;
    private static final String DROP_TABLE_RotationVector = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_RotationVector;
    private static final String DROP_TABLE_Magnetometer = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Magnetometer;
    private static final String DROP_TABLE_Orientation = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_Orientation;

    private Context context;

    public SensorsDBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_Version);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ACCELEROMETER);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_GYROSCOPE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LinearAcceleration);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_RotationVector);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_Magnetometer);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_Orientation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception", e+"========================================>");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_ACCELEROMETER);
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_GYROSCOPE);
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_LinearAcceleration);
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_RotationVector);
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_Magnetometer);
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_Orientation);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Exception", e+"========================================>");
        }
    }
}}
```

the Logcat is

```
05-14 08:16:27.035 15796-15796/com.ttt.ddd.sdc_v2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ttt.ddd.sdc_v2, PID: 15796
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.ttt.ddd.sdc_v2.SenosorsDBAdapter.insert(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, float, float, float)' on a null object reference
    at com.ttt.ddd.sdc_v2.AccelerometerThread.onSensorChanged(AccelerometerThread.java:53)
    at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:833)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

Thread

```
public class AccelerometerThread extends Thread implements Runnable ,SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private Context context;
private SenosorsDBAdapter mSensorsDBAdapter;



public AccelerometerThread (Context applicationContext) {
    context=applicationContext;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if (mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null) {
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        mSensorsDBAdapter=new SenosorsDBAdapter(context);
    }
}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    String date;
    float x,y,z;

    String sensorname=event.sensor.getName();
    int sysnsortype=event.sensor.getType();

    x=event.values[0];
    y=event.values[1];
    z=event.values[2];
    String sx=Float.toString(x);
    String sy=Float.toString(y);
    String sz=Float.toString(z);
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss");
    date = s.format(new Date());

    if(date!=null&&sx!=null&&sy!=null&&sz!=null){
        AppConstant.Accelerometer_x=x;
        AppConstant.Accelerometer_y=y;
        AppConstant.Accelerometer_z=z;
        AppConstant.Accelerometer_ST=sysnsortype;
        AppConstant.Accelerometer_sensornsme=sensorname;
        AppConstant.Accelerometer_date=date;
```

mSensorsDBAdapter.Accelerometerinsert(sysnsortype,sensorname,date,x,y,z);
        }

```
    Log.i("Accelerometer_running",date+"=========================>");
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

}

Comment: Please post the crash logcat.

Comment: I added the  logcat @KoustuvGanguly

Comment: Show me the code in AccelerometerThread.java:53